# Define column headlines in row A sheet2, before I copy from sheet1 to sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

A kind person helped me with me previous question and this should work out the problem, and it does. Now the problem is that I have 10 files to make a data input from, so I make a data input for the first file and then I want to take the first 3 rows.

So the first row is the headline of the column, and row 2 and 3 is the data I want. How can I add some code, that will take the first three rows in sheet1, copy them, and paste them in the first 3 rows available. Then I delete the data in sheet1, make a new data input with different data (still the same headlines for the columns, and I want the same columns with copied), and gets the data in sheet2.

But the problem would be that I don't want the 3 first rows when I make my second, third and so on, data input. Every data input besides the first, I want row 2 and 3. Is there a smart way to do it?

Is it easier to define what should be in the first row in sheet2, than copy it? If it is, how can I define a headliner for each column in sheet2 before I make the copy?

```
Option Explicit

Sub call_copy_sub_ranges()
    Dim super_range As Range
    Set super_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Columns("A:T")

    Dim output_sheet As Worksheet
    Set output_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")

    copy_sub_ranges super_range, output_sheet

End Sub

Sub copy_sub_ranges(ByVal super_range As Range, ByVal output_sheet As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Range

    Set r = super_range.Range("A1:A2")
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("B1:B2"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("E1:E2"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("H1:H2"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("I1:I2"))

    Dim offset As Long
    If IsEmpty(output_sheet.Range("a1").Value) Then offset = 0 Else offset = 1

    'output_sheet.Cells(output_sheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) locates the bottom of anything already in column A
    r.Copy output_sheet.Cells(output_sheet.Cells.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).offset(offset, 0)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshot with an example of what you want to copy to which destination exactly? It would be much easier to understand then. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

:o)

Is this it?

```
Option Explicit

Sub call_copy_sub_ranges()
    Dim super_range As Range
    Set super_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Columns("A:T")

    Dim output_sheet As Worksheet
    Set output_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")

    copy_sub_ranges super_range, output_sheet

End Sub

Sub copy_sub_ranges(ByVal super_range As Range, ByVal output_sheet As Worksheet)

    Dim offset As Long
    If IsEmpty(output_sheet.Range("a1").Value) Then offset = 0 Else offset = 1 endif


    Dim r As Range
    Set r = super_range.Range("A1:A2")
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("B" & (2-offset) & ":B3"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("E" & (2-offset) & ":E3"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("H" & (2-offset) & ":H3"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("I" & (2-offset) & ":I3"))


    'output_sheet.Cells(output_sheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) locates the bottom of anything already in column A
    r.Copy _
    output_sheet.Cells(output_sheet.Cells.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).offset(offset, 0)
 End Sub
```